# How to record an old Foscam system’s live feed locally?

Tags: video

I just inherited an old Foscam wireless / wired, pan/tilt IP camera model FI8918W. Due to its age, Foscam no longer supports. Rather than tossing it, I was able to stream video to my browser using `mjpeg`

```sh
http://[ip_address]:[port_number]/videostream.cgi?user=[username]&pwd=[password]
```

But I cannot save the video.

I would like to stream and save the video locally to an unused Windows 10 machine (with an enormous HD). But, the only option available was to save an image from the live feed. My goal is to be able to record the live feed, review it, then delete or save it depending.

Any suggestions on accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On what OS would you like to do this? I assume Linux and [thus have recommended FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/1835974/167207), but it would be nice to have your question edited to clarify that.

Comment: Your unused win10 box could be redeployed as a dedicated linux box ?

Answer (score 3):

Nice camera! There are any number of Windows applications that can record a video stream from a URL, such as free [VLC](https://www.videolan.org) (see [TechWalla](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-record-a-network-stream-with-vlc-media-player) for directions), free [OBS (Open Broadcast Studio)](https://obsproject.com) (see [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Save-Streaming-Video) for directions), and a slew of [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/vlc-media-player/).

You can also find old software for the camera at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/foscam-fi8918w-indoor-wireless-ip-camera-cd) (and if you want to try the camera on an Android device,  [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s=foscam)). **N.B.:** Check any software at [VirusTotal](https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s=foscam) before installing or trying it, and don't be surprised if the app doesn't work on newer Windows versions -- but you *could* run it in a VM on Windows.

Also, take reasonable precautions against opening that camera and your IP to the web.

Comment: *Also, take reasonable precautions against opening that camera and your IP to the web.* I scrapped a Foscam video baby monitor because it had become next to useless without a connection outside my network.

Answer (score 3):

Some other ideas:

1. [Use VLC to Convert/Transcode](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/) the video stream to a local file. [Another answer before mine also pointed this out](https://superuser.com/a/1835976/160219), I included it because I linked to another help article that was less ad-ridden.
2. Foscam camera webGUI sometimes have FTP settings. Setup FTP server on your PC, enter your PC's FTP server settings in Foscam webGUI.
3. Since webGUI on those older cameras is terrible you might have success with their [Foscam VMS, I have on Apple PC](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/foscam-vms/id1521202507).

Answer (score 3):

Something like [`motion`](https://motion-project.github.io/)                         running as a daemon on a Linux box, should be able to stream the video from the cameras and process it, only saving those segments where there was movement.

I've used motion since the noughties and it works with network cameras, USB cameras, and analogue capture cards.

`motion` is packaged in many linux distros too, for convenience. There's also an IRC channel #motion on Libera.chat

I have 9 cameras and 120 days of footage is 379 GB, as a data point. You will need this computer and disk running 24/7, and it needs enough CPU to process 10-30 frames per second.   I use a 10 core VM and the load average is solidly around 1.3 all day and a bit less at night; you could do fine with 2 cores.

[image]

Generic cheap AliExpress network cam, but would work similarly given your discovery of the MJPEG stream, which is just a stream of motion JPEGs strung together.

MJPEG uses a bit more bandwidth than H.264 but is still insignificant on a 100 Mbit or faster link.

---

Coincidentally [Foscam got a mention on the mailing list recently](https://sourceforge.net/p/motion/mailman/message/58752348/)

> Foscam is a good choice, if you can find them. AFAIK they've been out of business for several years.

Comment: I assume you're processing the stream and recompressing only when something happens, given that you need a fair bit of processing power but not a huge amount of storage (I'm just starting to think about a system with Motion, for max. 3 cameras)

Comment: @ChrisH In $JOB-2 I had to watch tape, and it was tedious- you couldn't blink for missing something relevant.   Why do that 20 years later when we have the technology?

Comment: @Criggie I wasn't necessarily thinking the alternative was watching it, but dumping everything to disc and running motion detection later if required. But I want low power consumption. I'm also doing stuff with video image recognition of a very different kind for work at the moment, and finding significant performance issues on basic hardware.

Comment: @ChrisH since I did mine, there are some fancy image processing modules available now, I know Jeff Geerling did some work with them ... but I can't find more at a brief glance.   "Tensor" perhaps ?  Making this stuff work much better on a Pi-grade device.

Comment: Are you thinking the coral chips google was selling?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek YES!   https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2023/pcie-coral-tpu-finally-works-on-raspberry-pi-5   that was the missing word.   Whether this can help with OP's problem I don't know, I've never used one.

Comment: I think someone else on youtube was using them too - I vaguely think it was hardware haven using the m.2 varient of it. *But* it was the one that came to mind, and outside 'ab'using a gpu, the commonly available thing for that sorta work

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26464175/117259), this should work fine with FFmpeg; updated the answer to use the URL you provided:

```sh
ffmpeg -i http://[ip_address]:[port_number]/videostream.cgi?user=[username]&pwd=[password] -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "outfile.mp4"
```

You need to run this command from the command line (Windows) or Terminal (macOS or Linux) after you install FFmpeg.

In this example, it will create an output file named `outfile.mp4` of the input URL stream.

Comment: Thank you, Giacomo1968, for considering my question. I am going to try FFmpeg and report the result.

Comment: Well, I tried using the URL above, but instead of opening the URL, my browsers (FF, Chrome) each searched for the URL instead of opening it. Interestingly, the URL I initially used opened the video stream almost instantly.  Not so with the "ffmpeg" URL. I haven't given up yet, and will continue trying to access this URL. I will report the result later today/tonight

Comment: @Umrk That's not an URL, that's a console command. You'll have to have ffmpeg program installed and type that in your OS's command prompt.

Comment: Not sure about this specific camera, but _in general_ saving these sorts of HTTP streaming protocols can be split into separate steps: 1) download the raw data over a range of time with a long-running `curl`, then later 2) run `ffmpeg` over the saved data and have it discard the leading/trailing partial frames and reconstruct a valid standalone video file.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Agent DVR](https://www.ispyconnect.com/docs/agent/about) software on both Windows and linux (also available Docker-ized) with some ancient Arecont cameras with great success.  Not sure how it would deal with PTZ though; all my cameras are fixed.

Agent is basically a security camera DVR system with motion detection etc.  I've got it set up to save clips where motion is detected, and you can set up a maximum amount of disk space that it will use for storing clips.